# how do i set an alarm manager to fire every on specific day of week and time in android?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

for example i want to have an alarm that will fire every sunday at noon.... how would i do this?

Comment: I was wondering something very similar. Would there be a way to fire an event every 30 minutes to an hour? Maybe some cron job? Just wondering what Android had to offer for this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the AlarmManager class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

> Class Overview
>
> This class provides access to the
>   system alarm services. These allow you
>   to schedule your application to be run
>   at some point in the future. When an
>   alarm goes off, the Intent that had
>   been registered for it is broadcast by
>   the system, automatically starting the
>   target application if it is not
>   already running. Registered alarms are
>   retained while the device is asleep
>   (and can optionally wake the device up
>   if they go off during that time), but
>   will be cleared if it is turned off
>   and rebooted.

Use `public void set (int type, long triggerAtTime, PendingIntent operation)` to set the time to fire it.

Use `void setRepeating(int type, long triggerAtTime, long interval, PendingIntent operation)` to schedule a repeating alarm.

Here's a full example. I don't really remember all the Calendar methods, so I'm sure that part can be streamlined, but this is a start and you can optimize it later:

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmMAnager) Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar timeOff = Calendar.getInstance();
int days = Calendar.SUNDAY + (7 - timeOff.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)); // how many days until Sunday
timeOff.add(Calendar.DATE, days);
timeOff.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
timeOff.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
timeOff.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOff.getTimeInMillis(), yourOperation);
```

Comment: ya i know i need to use taht class just dont know how to get it to repeat every sunday at specified time

Comment: @will I updated the answer. It's part of the same AlarmManager api. Basically, you use an interval of a week 604,800,000 millis)

Comment: ok so how would i get sunday though just a little confused about this

Answer (score 0):

finally this right solution if set as (sun,tus ,fri) you must create three alarm for these three day 
the following code set alarm every sunday and send dayOfWeek=1;

```
 public void setAlarm_sun(int dayOfWeek) {
     cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sun "+cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK), 222).show();

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finsh", 222).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent0 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                intent, 0);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 12345,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

         Long alarmTime = cal1.getTimeInMillis();
         AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);

       // am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime,7* 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , pendingIntent);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime,7* 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , pendingIntent);

}
```