# execute service at particular time android

Tags: android

I am making GPS tracker application, and after 1 hrs I got the updated data and store into data base.
then at 12AM I want to send all data to particular email ID.
So what I have to use so it send email at 12AM only

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AlarmManager`. You set the time with:

```
setInexactRepeating (AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
    triggerAtTime, 
    myIntent, 
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

BTW, you do not want to execute a `Service` at that time. You want your `Service` to execute an `Activity`.

There's a snippet with details on how to implement it here: [Android: How to use AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager)

I actually answered before a similar question: [how do i set an alarm manager to fire every on specific day of week and time in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601678/how-do-i-set-an-alarm-manager-to-fire-every-on-specific-day-of-week-and-time-in-a/5601748#5601748)

Comment: I am confuse what will be the triggerAtTime value if I wan to execute at 12AM every day

Comment: @stuti you need to use a `Calendar` and set up when you want it (in millis). I added a new link with an answer of my own from some time ago that should help you.