# Set Alarm Manager for specific days in week

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am working on an android app for college work and I am trying to set a repeating alarms for specific days (or everyday. both options are possible).
Here is my code for this:

```
public void createAlarms(List<Reminders> medWreminders) {

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    for (int i = 0; i < medWreminders.size(); i++) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Calendar setcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, medWreminders.get(i).reminder.getHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, medWreminders.get(i).reminder.getMinutes());
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, medWreminders.get(i).reminder.getDayInt());

        // cancel already scheduled reminders
        notificationHelper.cancelNotification(this, medWreminders.get(i).reminder.getId());

        if (calendar.before(setcalendar)) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        // enable receiver
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this,
    AlertReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                medWreminders.get(i).reminder.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);

    }
```

It's important to mention that if the alarm is for daily basis, instead of setting one repeating alarm on a daily interval, (for other reasons) I'm setting 7 different alarms based on weekly interval- one for each day (which, I think, should behave the same). And remember, it is also for specific days in week.
So the problem is: if I set alarms- one for each day- at the same day it works but on the next day nothing happens.
Does anyone know the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Repeat days of week alarm in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894067/set-repeat-days-of-week-alarm-in-android)

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601678/how-do-i-set-an-alarm-manager-to-fire-every-on-specific-day-of-week-and-time-in